# Extending Enumerable in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This post is pretty much what I am after:

http://jablan.radioni.ca/post/2175717120/each-with-previous-in-ruby

The idea here that if I loop through a list of `@users` I would then see if their last initial changed and add an anchor (#T etc.) and link to it.

I am lost at how you load this into our Rails project.  Where exactly do you place your module file:

```
module Enumerable
  def each_with_prev
    self.inject(nil){|prev, curr| yield prev, curr; curr}
    self
  end
end
```

I have seen references to the /lib folder and the concerns folders but none of these are clear.

Comment: Note that [`enum.each_cons(2)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) does almost the same thing. (The only difference is that `each_with_prev` uses `nil` as the "first" value, which is useful in some cases.)

Comment: I saw that and in my case I think I need that.  The first loop through each would need to display the anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

save your file to config/initializers/enumerable.rb

**Solution 2**

you can put your file to the /lib folder, and then add the following line to `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
```

Comment: do I name it enumerable.rb?